# How do I force boost::asio to prioritize finishing async_write calls over running other handlers?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am implementing a set of simple protocols using boost::asio (oblivious transfer schemes).  These are CPU bound when they run. To improve efficiency, I want to try to keep both hosts working as much as possible.  If host A has the choice between preforming two tasks, one of which would let host B start computation, and one which wouldn't, I want host A to pick the former.

Currently, io_service is running computationally intensive handlers before async_writes.  Unless the tcp window is full (or some similar condition is blocking writing data to the socker), it's almost certainly better to finish the async_write rather than running some other handler.

I have seen asio's example of a priority queue for handlers.  Is reimplementing async_write to use such a priority queue the only solution to my problem?

Answer (score 4):

There's [an example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp) in the documentation describing how to attach a priority to completion handlers. You won't need to reimplement `async_write`, just implement your own version of the `handler_priority_queue` class from the example.

Comment: I saw that example. I don't understand how to attach a priority to async_write.  Since the write is asynchronous, I believe there are completion handlers being called internal to async_write. If so, I need to boost their priority.

Comment: @Amy are you concerned that `async_write` is a composed operation?

Comment: I'm concerned that async_write isn't a completion handler (I assume this means something which implements Handler and is passed to io_service::post.)  I'm also concerned about the fact that async_write is a composed operation.

Comment: I see now that asio_handler_invoke takes care of this.